# How do I reset hugo's content listing cache?

Tags: hugo

I accidentally created content with the wrong path using `hugo new content/my-page` as opposed to `hugo new my-page`, and now the content (and its folder) keeps reappearing when I delete the `content/content` folder.

How do I get rid of this post for good? There doesn't appear to be a `hugo delete` command - so where is this information stored?

Comment: You can try deleting the my-page.md followed by deleting the content folder. It should work.

Comment: @aditya-m-p did @yuvraj-gupta solution work? I would suggest to do the same. By the way, I avoid using `hugo new` completely, it's best to manually clone .md template file (or previous article) and edit it.

Comment: I am unable to respond because the problem appears to have gone away, but doing the same thing earlier didn't seem to work. Thought I'll come back to this question when I can confirm what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using `hugo serve` to test your site?

If so, this is a side-effect of the hugo cache - in order to remain quick, deleted and renamed files will remain in the cache, and can thus be accessed. By restarting the server, the cache is cleared; which is why your problem fixed itself.

This isn't usually a problem, as you can rebuild the site at any time, and clear the cache when doing so.

I think you have a two options:

1 - ignore the files during development, knowing they will not exist in production

2 - restart the server after deleting or renaming files

Either way, *knowledge* of the problem is part of the solution.